# Select only an array of dates Jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a `php array` that returns a available day of the week already converted in number this 1,2,5 for (Monday, Thursday, Friday). 
Now i have function like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataritiro').datepicker({
      minDate: 0,
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 1 && day != 2)];
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

But i have trouble to use it with the provided array. I need that days available is dynamically fetched from the array that I pass trough `var days = <?php echo $days; ?>`

Comment: `return [days.indexOf(day) !== -1]`, given `days` is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to translate your php array to a javascript array, then do something like @arun-p-johny suggested

```
var days = (<php echo json_encode($array); ?>);
...
return [days.indexOf(day) !== -1]
```